# Doctrine Criteria() matching DBALException

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `FbUserEntity` which has an `ArrayCollection` of many `PageEntity`.

```
 $fbUser->getPageLikes(); 

 //will give back an array of many PageEntity classes:
  object(stdClass)[1410]
     public '__CLASS__' => string 'MyBundle\Entity\PageEntity' (length=41)
     public 'id' => int 877
     public 'fbId' => string '8245623462' (length=10)
     public 'name' => string 'NBA' (length=3)
```

I have an array of facebookId's, like :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '8245623462' (length=10)
  1 => string '1239653462' (length=10)
```

I want to get those `PageEntity` entities from the $`fbUser` where the `fbId` of the `PageEntity` can be found in the other array (In fact I only need if any of the array items can be found in the `PageEntity` collection). Inspecting example I made the following code:

```
/* @var FbUserEntity $fbUser */
  $uLikes = $fbUser->getPageLikes();
  $criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->in("fbId", $qLikes))
    ->setMaxResults(1);

  $preferred = $uLikes->matching($criteria);
```

And when executing I get an error message:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT te.id AS id, te.fbId AS fbId, te.name AS name FROM Page te JOIN Page_Like t ON t.page = te.id WHERE t.user = ? AND te.fbId = ?' with params [22, ["8245623462","1239653462"]]: 
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

The interesting is that `Criteria::expr()->in()` expects argument 2 to be an array, and it is. The other thing is shouldn't that internal query use `AND te.fbId IN (?)` instead of `AND te.fbId = ?` ?

Comment: use [22, "8245623462","1239653462"] instead of [22, ["8245623462","1239653462"]]

Comment: @Mohammad Zare Moghadam how can I change that? That queris is internally generated, I just pass an array to Criteria::expr()->in("fbId", $qLikes) as it expects.

Comment: I recommend you create a DQL to solve this.